# MySQL Query - Translating Multiple Columns

Tags: mysql

I was wondering if someone could help with this MySQL query. Found it difficult to search for an answer as don't know what kind of query this is.

This is the output table desired:

```
ID     Capital1  Capital2  Capital3
Maps1  Paris     London    Rome
```

This the the Maps Table

```
ID      Country1  Country2  Country3
Map1    France    UK        Italy
```

This is the Country Table

```
*Country*   *Capital*
France    Paris
UK        London
Italy     Rome
Spain     Madrid
Greece    Athens
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your question? Perhaps join the country table with the maps table on those fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join the `country` table 3 times with different alias names

```
select m.id, 
       c1.capital as capital1,
       c2.capital as capital2,
       c3.capital as capital3
from maps m
left join country c1 on c1.country = m.country1
left join country c2 on c2.country = m.country2
left join country c3 on c3.country = m.country3
```

BTW you should actually normalize your table design and don't store the countries in the the `maps` table.

Comment: depending on the use case you might want to change to an `INNER JOIN`. but this is the solution

Comment: Thank you - this works but returns a lot of results.  What is the best way to limit results to WHERE ID='Map1'.

Comment: And yes, probably one reason that I couldn't find an answer is that the table should be normalised

Comment: Nevermind, changing to INNER JOIN and adding a 'AND m.id = "Maps1" worked to the first join worked.  Thanks